# Slider - 3 handles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got the current slider

```
<input id="slider_price" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="1000" data-slider-max="80000" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[60000, 80000]"/>
```

_

```
$('#slider_price').slider({
    tooltip: 'always'
});
```

[image]

This is working great as it is but now I want to extend it, I want to add a third slider, like this:

[image]

I have browsed through the whole manual and guides, but there are no examples how you can use 3 handles in a slider!

Help is greatly appreciated!
Tompa

Answer (score 2):

Try this, i think it helps you

```
$('#slider_price').slider({
    tooltip: 'always',
    values: [21690,47590,72475]
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion, sadly it didn't work. Still only 2 handles

Comment: That's something to start with! I'll keep the question unanswered for now to see if anyone else has a suggestion! Thanks a lot!